# Determine if a file is script or not

Tags: linux

I am wondering that how can I Use the **file** command and  determine if a file is a script or not.for example in  **usr bin** I want to know which file is script or not. actually i don't want write any script just i need a command for determine that.

Comment: how would you do it 'manually'?  check typical settings for execution, extension, and maybe look at the contents (parse it)

Comment: what's a script? shell/perl/awk.. ?

Comment: just i have to use command not any shhe/perl/awk

Comment: how try it again, in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly trust file to find any script in the directory you specify:

```
file /usr/bin/* | grep script
```

Or, if you prefer to do it yourself and you are using bash you can do:

```
for f in /usr/bin/*; do r=$(head -1 $f | grep '^#! */') && echo "$f: $r"; done
```

which uses the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to determine the interpreter and thus the script entity.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (assuming that you're using BASH):

```
for f in `ls`; do file $f|grep "executable"; done
```

Update- I just validated that this works for C shell scripts, BASH, Perl, and Ruby.  It also ignores file permissions (meaning that even if a file doesn't have the executable bit set, it still works).  This seems to be do to the file command looking for a command interpreter (bash, perl, etc…)

Comment: It's working for me, the grep part pulls out the executable ones.

Comment: well, what else do you have in /usr/bin? normally they are all executable (note: I'm not sure what the OP meant by *script*, see my comment..)

Comment: Sorry to miscommunicate, I did it in one of my dev directories that had .rtf, .pdf, and .sh files (some without the chmod +x set and some with).  It only pulled out the ones that were actual script files, regardless of the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`file` can't guarantee to tell you anything about a text file, if it doesn't know how to interpret it.

You may need to do a combination of things. jschorr's answer should probably work for the stuff in /bin, but another way to test a file might be to check whether a text file is executable.

```
stat -c "%A" myfilename | grep x
```

If that returns anything, then your file has execute permissions on it. So if `file` gets you a description that tells you it's plain text (like `"ASCII text"`), and there are execute permissions on the file, then it's a pretty good bet that it's a script file.

Not perfect, but I don't think anything will be.